# .net 4.0 and telerik versions support

Tags: asp.net, telerik

We plan to upgrade our .net project from 2.0 to 4.0. We are using telerik controls in our project. Telerik controls seems like older version and dont know what version it is. My question is what are the telerik versions supports by .net 4.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

The Telerik [ASP.Net AJAX controls](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx) support .Net 4.0 today, and have supported .Net 4.0 for the last year.

For more information about the versions of .Net and other frameworks the AJAX controls support, check this tech sheet:
http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/getting-started/tech-sheets/system-requirements.aspx